# Additive Order and Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In an integral Domain, Additive order of each element is same and prime.(each equal to characteristic of ring) Is converse also true?

Q1. Given additive order of each element same in a ring, would it be integral domain?

Q2. Given additive order of each element prime in a ring, would it be integral domain?

Q3. Given additive order of each element same and prime in a ring, would it be integral domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $F$ is the field of $p$ elements, $F\times F$ is a counterexample to all three.

Also, strictly speaking, it is never going to be possible to get *all* elements to have prime order. The zero element, at least, will have order $1$.

Finally, the first sentence should include that the characteristic could be $0$ (but if course, when it is nonzero and the ring is a domain, it is prime as you say.